# How to check that @Async call completed in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

Im using **@Async** annotation for method that execute rsync command. There are **ten threads** calling this method at a time. My requirement is after all ten threads complete rsync command execution then only my remaining code should execute but not getting how to check whether my all ten threads has executed @Async method completely or not? So please tell me a way to check it

Comment: Write an entry in a database or pass a message to a queue.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you are going to return some value, you should wrap your return value into Standard Java SE `Future` or Spring's [`AsyncResult`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/AsyncResult.html), which implements `Future` also.

Something like this:

```
@Component
class AsyncTask {
  @Async
  public Future<String> call() throws InterruptedException {
    return new AsyncResult<String>("return value");
  }
}
```

If you do have this in place, in caller you do something like:

```
public void kickOffAsyncTask() throws InterruptedException {
  Future<String> futureResult =  asyncTask.call();

  //do some stuff in parallel

  String result = futureResult.get();
  System.out.println(result);
}
```

Call `futureResult.get()` will block caller thread and wait until your async thread finishes.

Optionally you can use `Future.get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` if you don't want to wait forever.

EDIT:

If you don't need to return any value, I would still suggest to consider returning dummy return value. You don't need to use it for anything, just use to indicate that particular thread completed. Something like this:

```
public void kickOffAsyncTasks(int execCount) throws InterruptedException {
  Collection<Future<String>> results = new ArrayList<>(execCount);

  //kick off all threads
  for (int idx = 0; idx < execCount; idx++) {
    results.add(asyncTask.call());
  }

  // wait for all threads
  results.forEach(result -> {
    try {
      result.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
      //handle thread error
    }
  });

  //all threads finished
}
```

Comment: Im not returning any value what i was doing is running a for loop for 150 folders (1 folder per loop iteration) for sync the data using rsync command with @Async and my requirement is after rsync completed for all 150 folders need to parse data in the folder

Comment: I'd just like to mention that if you used `CompletableFuture`, your `// wait for all threads` block could be replaced by `CompletableFuture.allOf(results).join()`.